# Golang beego framework to set the status code

Tags: web, go, beego

I am using Golang to write web applications, and I use beego framework. It seems the the framework have the internal status code returned for golang web server.

I am wondering is there any method in golang or beego, or other tools that can let me control the status code returned to browser, say 200, or 500 or others number.

Comment: can we have some source code to work with?

Answer (score 6):

In your controller you can access the `http.ResponseWriter` via the `Ctx`

```
type SomeController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (c *SomeController) Get() {
    c.Ctx.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(500)
}
```

Edit: After further inspection you should probably do this:

```
func (c *SomeController) Get() {
    c.CustomAbort(500, "Internal server error")
}
```

I'm leaving the reference about the context because you can find the `http.Request` and `http.ResponseWriter` on controller's `Ctx` property.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on [`http.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter). If you have access to the `ResponseWriter`-object, you can easily return your own [HTTP status code](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-constants).

Answer (score 1):

```
c.Abort("500")
```

it response HTTP code is 200.

Must be:

```
c.Ctx.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(500)
```

Answer (score -1):

Very late to the party. I m able to set status on beego v2.0.2.

```
func (u *UserController) Post() {
    var user models.User
    json.Unmarshal(u.Ctx.Input.RequestBody, &user)
    uid, _ := models.AddUser(&user)
    u.Data["json"] = map[string]interface{}{"uid": uid}
    u.Ctx.Output.Status = http.StatusCreated #<<<------------
    u.ServeJSON()
}
```